# auto rotate stops music when app rotates

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-mediaplayer

I added

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

To the activity in the manifest but the app still rotates if the device is turned. Cannot add all of code yet, on phone. But will add when i get back home.

Comment: The code will be definitely required.

Comment: Yeah start work in 10mins so wont have it up for 4 hrs

Comment: Put your Manifest file

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you need from the few lines you wrote. It looks like you are creating a music player app and you are facing the problem that music stops playing when changing the orientation of the device. It also looks like your solution to this problem is to prevent screen orientation changes. If I got it right, you can prevent screen orientation by putting the following line in your Activity tag inside the manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

The music stops playing because when screen orientation changes, the system destroys and recreates the Activity. If you cut away `screenSize` from the line above, the system will not destroy your Activity, thus the music will keep playing, but the user will still be able to rotate the screen. Moreover, if your application is actually a music player I would consider other ways of implementing it, such as background services.

Comment: That is the problem and the solution i used snd i will try it now. The thing is, when my device is connected via cable to my laptop, and i run the music player as android application,  tge screen oridntation stays portrait no matter what. When the devicd is unplugged, the screen will change orientation when the device is turned

Answer (score 0):

You can set the orientation in two ways:

I. Programatically:

```
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

II. In your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".activity"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```